# Run Same Javascript Multiple Times Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am currently injecting a Javascript file into a webpage from a chrome extension in order to auto-fill and submit a form on the webpage. Furthermore, I need this script to continuously auto-fill and execute the script. However, the form submission only will occur at the end of the script, forcing me to run the entire script multiple times rather than use a loop on the script's content. How can I go about running the same Javascript file over and over on a webpage? The method I am currently doing seems to fail and runs the script only once.

Here is my current background.js:

```
// listen for our browerAction to be clicked
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
executeScripts(null, [ 
    { file: "inject.js" }, 
    { file: "inject.js" },
    { file: "inject.js" },
    { code: "inject.js" }
])
});
```

Inject.js is the Javascript file that I want to run multiple times. Here is the simplified version of the script:

```
(function() {
   var text = "hello";
   var url = "www.google.com"

   document.getElementById('personaName').value = text;
   document.getElementById('customURL').value = url;

   var form = document.getElementById("editForm");
   form.submit();
 })();
```

Comment: After submitting the form, your web page will be refreshed or redirected, do you want to inject the same script to different pages?

Comment: I want to inject the same script to the exact same web page after refresh.

Comment: If you use `manifest.json` injection, then the scripts will be automatically injected every time the page loads, including you refresh the page.

Comment: Interesting, but I am looking for a way to launch this process when I click the extension, rather than it auto-starting when I load the web page

Comment: Then your question becomes clicking browser action then execute content scripts, is that right? So calling `chrome.tabs.executeScript` or using message passing just solves it.

Comment: What's `executeScripts`? Where is its code?

Comment: Partially, Haibara. I need a script to run over and over after I have clicking browser action. When using executeScript, it only runs that code once.

Comment: @user1939991, then why not put this logic inside `inject.js`? Wrap your function code inside `setInterval` in `inject.js`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a function, func, every x milliseconds you can do:

```
setInterval(func, x);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! Would I run execute scripts as the repeating function, or how exactly should I go about utilizing this to continuously call the function?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to run this on an interval as opposed to setting event listeners and running it when there is a change?

Comment: There is not. I am just looking for some way to continuously execute the inject.js script.

Comment: The best way to do this is to add event listeners to the inputs you want to monitor, and when those fire, call the function you want to run.